# WPF: Popup always floats on top. How do i correct that?

Tags: wpf

The popup that gets opened in my app always stays on top. It goes away when i minimize the app. But otherwise if the app opens a new window or if i switch to another program without minimizing the app, the popup stays on top. How do i hide the popup when the app loses focus?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Pop up is appearing over other desktop windows, how to only appear on top of the WPF main window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561891/wpf-pop-up-is-appearing-over-other-desktop-windows-how-to-only-appear-on-top-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the owner/parent of the popup to the correct window by setting the Owner property to the window that created it.

Comment: And how would you do this ? The Owner property of a Window needs to be a Window which is not a popup?

Comment: @esylvestre: when you create the popup, set the popup's Owner to be the window visible when it was created (e.g. the main application window)

Comment: How to setup Owner of a Popup?

Comment: @sll: After `Popup pop = new Popup();` Add a line: `pop.Owner = x` where `x` is the window you want to be the owner (e.g. if you're in the code of the owning window x is `this`).

Comment: @Jackson Pope: unfortunately I can't access Owner property

Comment: @sll, then try setting the `Parent` property.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? It doesn't work or do I miss something?

Comment: Think there was some confusion in the answers making the distinction between a Popup "Window" and the WPF Popup control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/popup-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8.

I was able to get the desired behavior using the answer that subclasses Popup (Also not the accepted answer in this post). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606954/popup-always-stays-on-top

Answer (score 0):

You can pass owner (parent window) to the constructor of the popup window and then specify

```
public class PopupWindow: Window
{
    public PopupWindow(Window owner)
    {
        this.Owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Then open your popup window

Now to open your popup window you will use something like this:

```
var popup = new PopupWindow(ownerWindow);
popup.Show();
```

or if caller is a parent (owner)

```
var popup = new PopupWindow(this);
popup.Show();
```