# Dialogue box opens behind the wpf popup

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have created the application in Wpf. i am facing the problem here that when i am opening the popup i have placed file up-loader for file uploading when i click the browse button for upload file the dialogue box is opening behind the popup. But it should opens in front of popup If anybody knows please help me. Thanks in advance.

My popup is something like that:

```
                    <Button  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="btnaddactivity" Width="140" Height="40" FontSize="12" Content="Save Project" Foreground="White" Background="#FFF3800C" Margin="631,425,99,-58"  />


                    <Expander x:Name="expander" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"     Foreground="White" FontFamily="segoe_uilight" Height="200"  Width="326" Canvas.Right="20" Canvas.Left="1000"  BorderBrush="#FF0A0909" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Background="#FFF3800C" Margin="0,188,73,19" Loaded="expander_Loaded"  >
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="243">

                                <Canvas Height="22" Width="145" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

                                    <Image x:Name="imagebind1" Height="30" Width="45" RenderTransformOrigin="2.75,0.8" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="3" />
                                </Canvas>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="261" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="39*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="64*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ListBox  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  BorderBrush="#FFF3800C" Name="icTodoList2" Background="#FFF3800C" Margin="23,10,-47,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="285" MouseUp="icTodoList2_MouseUp">
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/1.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/2.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/3.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Tag="-1"/>

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/4.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/6.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/7.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/8.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>
                                    <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="30" Width="30" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image  Source="img/icons/9.png"  Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Expander>

                </Grid>

            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this, its similar to your question.

[Popup always stays on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606954/popup-always-stays-on-top)

Here they create a custom popup using [user32.dll](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/non-topmost-wpf-popup/)