# WPF popup animation not always centered on customer hardware

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application with a popup showing an animation while the application is busy. It's simply:

```
     <Popup Name="popupInitialise" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Center" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRootGrid}" IsOpen="{Binding IsInitialisingState}">
        <control:LoadingAnimation Background="Transparent"/>
     </Popup>
```

where LayoutRootGrid is the container of the entire control.

I've never seen it but on customer hardware the popup sometimes appears in the top left corner rather than centred.

What could be the cause? Does the graphics driver play any part in the placement of this item?

Thanks

Comment: is `LayoutRootGrid` centered to screen?

Comment: It's running in full screen

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue when one of our customers was using a different DPI setting other than the default of 100%. To get around the issue we have to use the
[CustomPopupPlacement option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743607(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: Meh, that would just make it off-center, not put it at the far top left corner.

Comment: @HansPassant you make a good point! We saw the exact same behaviour as mentioned in the original question and the only 2 things we changed where the custom placement and then we used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606954/popup-always-stays-on-top/18509629#18509629) to prevent the popup from displaying above other applications (I didn't think this would help as David mentioned he is running the application in fullscreen). I would be keen to know the actual cause of this issue.