# WPF ComboBox - If expanded, stays on top of all windows

Tags: wpf, combobox, z-order

I have a WPF form with ComboBox on it.  If I expand my combobox, then open an app such as Notepad or any other, the app will cover my WPF form but the expanded ComboBox portion will still be on top.  So it appears as the Notepad app is between the WPF form and its expanded portion of ComboBox (the combo box dropdown).  It looks like the ComboBox will show its expanded dropdown always at the top of z-order.
This is causing few other issues such as beeing unable to close the WPF form.
This is simply wrong.

[image]

Above:

- z-1 is z-order of my WPF form with expanded ComboBox (but note that the expanded area is on top of applications opened and overlapping the WPF form
- z-2 is order of Notepad application opened and overlapping my WPF form with the ComboBox on it (again, you can see that Notepad overlaps WPF form but the ComboBox expanded dropdown overlaps Notepad.  It should be behind Notepad, not in front of it)
- z-3 is the expanded dropdown of my ComboBox located on WPF form with z-1 order

My ComboBox is part of UserControl and its xaml is like this

```
    <ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSet}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Name"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
              BorderBrush="Green" 
              BorderThickness="2">
    </ComboBox>
```

How do I prevent the issue in the provides screenshot?

Comment: What's your question? :) The default control template for a WPF combobox uses the Popup control for the expanded combobox itemslist, which I believe has OS level priority in terms of what layer it appears on.

Comment: @Rowbear Please see the update.I think it will make more sense after seeing the screenshot and updated explanation.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" this by setting the WPF form containing my ComboBox as TopMost="True" in its xaml.  Not perfect fix but at least removes the stupid look and all other problems it leads to I discovered.  I cannot believe that MS made this default behavior, it is plain stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the behavior is in most cases "wrong"; when would you really want a dropdown to stay open if focus is lost on the current application? However, as I mentioned in my comment, that is the designed behavior of the Popup control. A WPF combobox under the hood is actually a ToggleButton with a Popup control that is set to open when the ToggleButton is toggled. So... the way to prevent the issue you're seeing is to prevent the Popup control from staying on top of all applications.

There's a StackOverflow question for that :)
[Popup always stays on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606954/popup-always-stays-on-top)

One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18509629/3063835) actually has code snippet with a derived/custom popup control that uses user32.dll to prevent the undesired behavior.

So ok great, that's how you fix a Popup, but how do you fix a ComboBox? You simply have to override the default ControlTemplate to use the fixed-non-top-most Popup control instead of the standard WPF Popup.

Comment: Thanks but I decided to go as described below.  Much appreciated.