# WPF Pop up is appearing over other desktop windows, how to only appear on top of the WPF main window?

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a WPF main window that has a grid and i have added a WPF pop up to ask the user for extra info when a button is clicked. But the problem is that when other desktop windows are moved over the pop up, the pop up covers the other desktop windows. How to fix this so the pop up is only top most of the WPF main window and not other desktop windows. The pop up is behaving like the task manager when set to always on top!

If you use the below code you will see that the pop up stays on top. So move any other desktop window over the pop up and the pop up will cover the other desktop application! Note that i do not want to use StaysOpen="False".

```
<Grid>
    <Popup Name="myPopup" Placement="Center" IsOpen="True">
        <StackPanel Background="Green" >
            <TextBox Width="200" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Name="closePopupBtn" Content="close" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set the Owner property in the popup window.
In your Popup Window,

```
this.owner = instanceOfParentWindow;
```

This is also similar to your question.

[Popup always stays on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606954/popup-always-stays-on-top)

Here they create a custom popup
[using user32.dll](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/non-topmost-wpf-popup/)

Comment: WPF popup doesn't have owner

Comment: Yeah, the question is not about WPF Window, but about WPF Popup element.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question, I've reached it by searching how to solve the same issue.

The very simplest way, working way to do is to replace the Popup by a Tooltip control.
The tooltip shares the same basic functionality but it does not act as a separate layer as popup does, thus Tooltip will not appear on top of other applications.

(Popup is not a Control the way WPF defines them, it's rather a component not intended to be used as is).

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue but have now found a workaround. This may not suit everyone, depending on how you control the popup's visibility, and what you expect to happen when your application window regains focus.

In my UI I have a Popup whose visibility is toggled by clicking a Button. The button is bound to an ICommand that sets a bool VM property. This in turn is bound to the popup's IsOpen property:

```
<Popup x:Name="ElementPopup"
       IsOpen="{Binding ShowPopup, Mode=OneWay}" ...>
```

Now, the issue was that users were clicking the button to display the popup, but tabbing away from our application window without first hiding the popup, then complaining that the popup was obscuring the newly focused window. My fix was to add the following trigger to the data template where the button resides. The trigger sets the Popup's IsOpen to false when the parent window is no longer active:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=IsActive}"
    Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="ElementPopup"
        Property="IsOpen"
        Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The popup is hidden when the application window loses focus, but interestingly it becomes visible again when the window becomes active again (I guess the IsOpen binding overrides the value set by the trigger). This latter behaviour suits us, as we want users to toggle the popup's visibility using the button, but this solution may not be suitable if you want the popup to remain hidden.